excel VBA: "=" delimiter not functioning upon import
I have a .qtx file type with comma, tab and "=" delimiters. An example string of data is "STD_Gloss=4.08". I want to separate the 4.08 into its own cell, hence the "=" delimiter.
Previously my code was working, and right now it will import the .qtx file and save it as a .xlsx file, but the delimiting is not including the "=".
Any thoughts on the reason for this error?
The segment of code I'm using is straightforward and I have found other examples using similar syntax. However, the reason for OtherChar:="=" not applying the custom delimiter is confusing me.
        Workbooks.OpenText filename:=folderPath & "\" & filename, Origin:=437, StartRow:= _
        1, DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
        ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, Semicolon:=False, Comma:=True, _
        Space:=False, Other:=True, OtherChar:="=", FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), _
        Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

Thanks!

Example of the code below
Sub ImportQTXSaveAsXLSX()
    Dim folderPath As String
    Dim savefolderPath As String
    Dim sourceWB As Workbook
    Dim sourceWS As Worksheet
    Dim filename As String
    
    folderPath = "U:\Macro for Gloss-O-Metre\QTX Raw"
    savefolderPath = "U:\Macro for Gloss-O-Metre\XLSX from QTX"
    
    If Right(folderPath, 1) <> "\" Then
        folderPath = folderPath & "\"
    End If
    
    If Right(savefolderPath, 1) <> "\" Then
        folderPath = folderPath & "\"
    End If
    
    filename = Dir(folderPath & "*.qtx")
    
    Do While filename <> ""
        Set sourceWB = Workbooks.Open(folderPath & "\" & filename)
                
        Workbooks.OpenText filename:=folderPath & "\" & filename, Origin:=437, StartRow:= _
        1, DataType:=xlDelimited, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, Semicolon:=False, Comma:=True, _
        Space:=False, Other:=True, OtherChar:="=", FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), _
        Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
        
        sourceWB.SaveAs savefolderPath & "\" & filename & ".xlsx", xlOpenXMLWorkbook
        sourceWB.Close SaveChanges:=False 
        filename = Dir     
End Sub


When you say an example string is "STD_Gloss=4.08" are the double quotes actually like that in the file? If so, then your TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote would tell excel to treat that entire string as a single column. Other than that, I don't see anything else in this code that would cause the behavior you are seeing.

@JNevill, the quotation marks are not in the original file. I too cannot understand why this wouldn't work for me all of the sudden. Thanks for the input

Odd stuff. I'm unable to replicate using your code.

@JNevill, I edited the post to hopefully help with replication if possible.

Oh. Apologies. I was able to replicate your code running successfully, I just couldn't make it replicate your issue. I should have been more clear. I created a test file with a few different scenarios using your example line, and only the line encapsulated in double quotes came through unsplit. I'm stumped.

If I understood your code correctly, the code you posted opens your text file twice. The first opening happens in the line Set sourceWB = Workbooks.Open(folderPath & "\" & filename). where Excel automatically converts the file in a way that you cannot control. The second line that opens the file is:
Workbooks.OpenText filename:=folderPath & "\" & filename, Origin:=437, StartRow:= _
        1, DataType:=xlDelimited, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, Semicolon:=False, Comma:=True, _
        Space:=False, Other:=True, OtherChar:="=", FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), _
        Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

This will convert the file according to your needs, but you do not save this file. Instead, you save the automatically converted file sourceWB. Since Workbooks.OpenText does not return a workbook object, you could adjust the loop as follows:
Do While filename <> ""
    'Set sourceWB = Workbooks.Open(folderPath & "\" & filename)
   Workbooks.OpenText filename:=folderPath & "\" & filename, Origin:=437, StartRow:= _
        1, DataType:=xlDelimited, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, Semicolon:=False, Comma:=True, _
        Space:=False, Other:=True, OtherChar:="=", FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), _
        Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
    Set sourceWB = ActiveWorkbook
    sourceWB.SaveAs savefolderPath & "\" & filename & ".xlsx", xlOpenXMLWorkbook
    sourceWB.Close SaveChanges:=False
    filename = Dir
Loop

By the way, you forgot to include the ending loop in your original post
